# Read <body> tag of HTML file using C#

Tags: c#, html

I need to get all the content inside the body tag of an HTML file using C#. Are there any good and effective ways of doing this?

Comment: Is this a file on disk or a webpage you're pulling down?

Comment: Sorry, just starting to accept, my mistake

Comment: and yes I'm the owner of the file that need parsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its easy enough to pull the page code into a string, and simply search for the occurrence of the string "<body" and the string "</body", and just do a little math to get your value...

Answer (score 9):

Check out the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) to do all sorts of HTML manipulation

It gives you an interface somewhat similar to the `XmlDocument` XML handling interface:

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.Load("file.htm");

 HtmlNode bodyNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body");

 if(bodyNode != null)
 {
    // do something
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You may take a look at [SgmlReader](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SgmlReader) and [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: That URL to SgmlReader leads to a very old version that hasn't been touched in years. The guys maintaining SgmlReader these days are MindTouch. I would recommend SgmlReader over HtmlAgilityPack due to its lower level approach and active maintenance. http://developer.mindtouch.com/en/docs/SgmlReader

Comment: If your HTML isn't wellformed XHTML I think you'll find that SgmlReader (and yeah use the mindtouch version as in the comment above) is your best bet.

Comment: @asbjomu - Looking through the conversion examples on the mindtouch site, I can't find a single one where SgmlReader produces a DOM that matches what browsers do. I don't know whether HTML Agility Pack is any better, but I wasn't impressed.

Comment: @Alohci I agree that SgmlReader isn't up to par with browser parsers, but there aren't many alternatives native to C# that does it better. HtmlAgilityPack surely doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

**Reading the Html Structure into Html String and Getting the Body Tag content using C# without HtmlAgility packages**

```
       private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string filepath = @"C:\Users\Testing\Documents\sample1.txt";
            string htmlString = File.ReadAllText(filepath);
            string htmlTagPattern = "<.*?>";
            Regex oRegex = new Regex(".*?<body.*?>(.*?)</body>.*?", RegexOptions.Multiline);
            htmlString = oRegex.Replace(htmlString, string.Empty);
            htmlString = Regex.Replace(htmlString, htmlTagPattern, string.Empty);
            htmlString = Regex.Replace(htmlString, @"^\s+$[\r\n]*", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
            htmlString = htmlString.Replace("&nbsp;", string.Empty);
        }
```

Comment: its not getting proper result.

Answer (score 0):

If it happens to be XHTML, then you could use XPath.

Answer (score 0):

Use XML methods, XPath. For more advanced manipulation with html use HTML Agility pack.

Answer (score 0):

To save you the math in the accepted answer:

```
var start = html.IndexOf("<body>") + "<body>".Length;
var end = html.IndexOf("</body>");
var result = html.Substring(start, end - start);
```

Mind that it's not 100% bulletproof:

- It will fail on CDATA blocks containing `<body>`
- It will fail if you have something like `<body lang="en">`

So all in all you are probably better off with the Agility Pack, unless you know for sure, which HTML you are working with.